# How to insert custom JS to WP after the document is ready/loaded

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, code-snippets

I get really annoyed that the block/part that is usually set for adding custom JS in Wordpress themes, is very small and not convenient to write in.

Searching for a way to add a bigger code, without child theme, in a way that it won't be over-written after update, and more convenient than the small box in: Customize -> General -> Custom CSS&JS.

Comment: Use the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ it has inbuilt Text editor with syntax highlighting, also theme or wordpress updates won't affect your js code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used Code Snippets plugin, but when using their example to add js, it loads the code in the beginning before the document has been loaded. This way, I couldn't edit the existing page/style/blocks/tags.

It's not very complicated but here's the small addition:

```
// ensure that query has been loaded to use: jQuery / $()
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
} );

// add your custom function
add_action( 'wp_head','my_custom_function'); 

function my_custom_function() { 
?>

<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
    // write your custom javascript code here
    // ...
  }

</script>
<?php }
```

Comment: for whatever it's worth. `.ready` has been deprecated in jQuery 3.5.  Use `jQuery(function(){//your custom jquery code here});` instead

Answer (score 0):

In file you are writing code must be called right before body tag and after your html code. Still if you want to use in same file then use below code with setTimeout.

```
    // ensure that query has been loaded to use: jQuery / $()
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
} );

// add your custom function
add_action( 'wp_head','my_custom_function'); 

function my_custom_function() { 
?>

<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // ...
        // write your custom javascript code here
        // ...
    },1000);
  }

</script>
<?php }
```